# How to use cookies in onsen ui

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I want to use cookies to temporary store some information. Onsenui guide doesn't introduce that. So I wonder how can I use cookies in Onsen ui.

Answer (score 0):

Onsen UI is a UI framework so there is no special way to handle cookies.

You can use the AngularJS `$ngCookies` service: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: thanks! Since I use ons.bootstrap in onsen ui, I can access to other angularJs via app..... What about angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies']). I wonder if it is included in ons.bootstrap or should I declare it as a new module.

Comment: You can use `angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies'])`. You can also use `ons.bootstrap(['ngCookies'])`

Comment: when I tried ons.bootstrap(['ngCookies']) i got error.

Comment: if you guys are talking about temporary storage, I'd suggest you to use
[LocalStorage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API):
`localStorage.setItem('colorSetting', '#a4509b');`

`localStorage.getItem('colorSetting');`

`localStorage.removeItem('colorSetting');`

`localStorage.clear();`

I've teste these on Chrome 46.0.2490.80 m, Firefox 42.0, Cordova on Android 4.2, 4.4 and 5.1 on various phone.